# Use Bayesian hierarchical model to predict new data points

Tags: beta-binomial-distribution

I have a data set $(n_i,y_i),i=0,...,10$. I modeled it as a Bayesian hierarchical beta-binomial model.

$y_i∼Binomial(n_i,p_i)$ and $p_i∼Beta(\alpha,\beta)$.

I have used MCMC to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (use the median as the estimated value).

Given a new $(n_j, y_j)$, I want to judge if it comes from the same model as the training set $(i=0,...,10)$, namely $p_j$ is significantly greater than $\theta$ (shrinkage $p_i$ from all group).

How can I use the estimated $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to compute it?

Answer (score 1):

In your notation, if you have a sample of, say, 1000 points from the posterior distribution of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (which you probably have, since you've MCMCed the model) stored in vectors `alpha` and `beta`, you can get a sample of 1000 points from the posterior predictive distribution $y_{11}\mid y_1,\dots,y_{10}$ doing `rbinom(1000, n_11, rbeta(1000, alpha, beta))`. With this sample, you can compute any desired summaries, such as the posterior predictive mean, build histograms, etc. Take a careful look at these [notes](http://www.stat.sc.edu/~hitchcock/stat535slidesday18.pdf) (especially page 7).

Comment: Thanks Zen. Given a new data point (nj,yj), I want to get the posterior probability (or something else ) that can illustrate pj is greater than p or equal to p . However, i can not write the formula of this posterior predictive distribution. What all I did is a MCMC for α , β and p. Should I incorporate the posterior predictive distribution into the process of MCMC.

Comment: The histogram that I've told you about gives the probability of each possible $y_{11}$, given the information in the training sample. If the probability of the observed $y_{11}$ is "high enough", then your model is predicting things well, and this gives a good "score" to your model and prior.

Comment: How did you compute the posterior of $\alpha,\beta$? Did you use BUGS, or did you code it yourself? Please, show us your code.

Comment: I used R to code this part. The key is to use the a combination of Gibbs and Metropolis-Hastings to draw  α , β and p from the posterior distributions. The iteration is 1000. The demo R code is from http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~brian/724/week06/lec15-mcmc2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In Bayesian statistics, such predictions as usually done using the posterior predictive distribution, not by estimating the parameters directly. See the Wikipedia page on the [posterior predictive distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution).

If the prior distribution is beta, and the likelihood is binomial, then the posterior predictive distribution is a beta-binomial distribution. See
[An introduction to the Beta-Binomial model](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~10701/lecture/technote2_betabinomial.pdf), which has details and formulas. The previous sentence beginning "If the prior distribution" is a direct quote from pg 8 of this document. Also see [the Wikipedia page on the Beta-binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).

You probably want the value of the posterior predictive distribution for your new data point to start with.

Comment: Thanks Faheem, I am more a programmer than a statistician can you tell me what is the formula of this posterior predictive distribution.

Comment: The formula is in the notes.

Comment: @user22062: I've edited the answer with a relevant link.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by doing a simulation to get a sample of $y$ values when $n=n_{new}$ from the training distribution. Then subtract of $y_{new}$ from the $y$ sample you got, and check if it's credibly non-zero. Here's some code to do that:

```
modelDescription = "
model {
    for( i in 1 : ny ) {
    y[i] ~ dbin(p[i],n[i])
    p[i] ~ dbeta(alpha,beta)
    }
    alpha ~ dunif(0,1e3)
    beta ~ dunif(0,1e3) #some priors...
}
"


sampleSize=500
y=rbinom(sampleSize,10,0.5)
n=round(y*10)-rbinom(sampleSize,2,0.5)+rbinom(sampleSize,2,0.5) #set p=1/10 with someRandomFluctuactions
n<-ifelse(n<1,1,n) #ensure all n>0

dataList = list(
    ny = length(y) ,
    y = y ,
    n = n
)

parameters = c("alpha","beta")

#this is just a wrapper I have for rjags::coda.samples and dclone::codaSamples
test1 = bjmCreate("model1",parameters,modelDescription,dataList,60000)

require(coda)
test1p <- window(test1,start(test1)+1000) #Burn-in
chain<-as.matrix(test1p)
alpha<-chain[,1]
beta<-chain[,2]
chainSize<-nrow(chain) #note that nrow(chain)==length(alpha)==length(beta)
```

In the code above, we got an alpha and beta sample from MCMC, now we are going to generate a sample for $y$ when $n=50$

We model $y$ as $y \sim Binomial(n,p)$. So to generate sample for $y$, we need to do `y<-rbinom(chainSize,newN,p)`.

We know the value of $n_{new}$, but we don't have $p$, but we can get a sample of it by remebering $p \sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$, so we get a $p$ sample from `p<-rbeta(chainSize,alpha,beta)`.

So, by pluging one thing into the other:

```
newN = 50 #setting here the value of N for which we'll predict y
p<-rbeta(chainSize,alpha,beta)
y<-rbinom(chainSize,newN,p)
```

Now we have a sample for $y$ when $n=50$, and our work would be done if we just wanted to predict it. But instead, you want to check if it an specific value of $y$ is from that distribution, so we do

```
newY = 5
yDiff <- y-newY
```

And check if the difference between both is credibly zero.

```
#Analisys of HPD
print(HPDinterval(mcmc(yDiff)))
densityplot(mcmc(yDiff))
```

I got the following result from `densityplot(mcmc(yDiff))`:

```
     lower upper
var1    -4     4
attr(,"Probability")
[1] 0.95
```

That is, zero is within the 95% HDP, and thus, we can not reject the hypothesis that the proposed $(y_{new},n_{new})$ "comes from the same model as the training set".

This, in fact, makes sense since the our "true" value p=1/10 is exactly the values we used ($y_{new}=5$ and $n_{new}=50$).

Comment: Thanks. I am just a beginner of statistics. I can not understand your code. Given a new data point (nj,yj), I want to get the posterior probability (or something else ) that can illustrate pj is greater than p or equal to p . However, i can not write the formula of this posterior predictive distribution. What all I did is a MCMC for α , β and p. Should I incorporate the posterior predictive distribution into the process of MCMC. Assume y represents some kinds of error, given a new data point like (nj=30,yj=8), how can I judge the new point's error rate is greater than the training set or not.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I'm not good in explaining stuff, I divided the code into many parts and further explained it, don't about the first block of code, it's just used to get a sample for alpha and beta, which you already have. Check if you can understand it now.

Comment: Just putting the text in another way, so it might help understand: in the second block of code, I predicted the value of y when we have n=50. In third block, I created a sample of the difference from that sample and the y you want to test. This difference should be zero if y comes from that distribution. So we check if this difference is credibly non-zero (in frequentist approach we would say, "significantly greater than zero", as you said).

Comment: Also, I recommend you to take a look at this book, it's easy to understand and has some pretty good explanations in Bayesian prediction and in analysis via HDI: [link](http://www.amazon.com/Doing-Bayesian-Data-Analysis-Tutorial/dp/0123814855)