# How to predict using Spatial temporal hierarchical bayesian models

Tags: prediction, inference, posterior, hierarchical-bayesian, spatio-temporal

I am using the R package CARBayesST to fit a Spatial-temporal Bayesian models. I want to use piece-wise ST model proposed by [Lee and Lawson, 2017](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/118843/1/118843.pdf).

The package does not have a built-in predict function. I saw this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53334/use-bayesian-hierarchical-model-to-predict-new-data-points), how to predict for new data points using posterior probability distribution, but I am not able to construct the same for Spatial temporal Bayesian models. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

There is even a [github page for CARBayesST](https://github.com/barryrowlingson/CARBayesST) created by @Spacedman, but I couldn't figure out how to predict using the code. In case that helps in finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the new data points with `NA` values for the response variable, in your training set. The model will calculate posterior probability distribution for them using data augmentation. If you save your model in the object `model`, you can access those posterior distributions through `model$samples$Y`. Unfortunately, this is only possible with `ST.CARlinear()`, `ST.CARanova()` and `ST.CARar()`, and not for the piece-wise model.