# Posterior Predictive CARBayesST

Tags: r, bayesian, predictive-models, spatio-temporal, car

I'm trying to use the CARBayesST package and I need to do Spatio-temporal predictions. In the vignette of the package on page 27 says " If there had been saying m missing values, then the Y component of the list would have contained m columns, with each one containing posterior predictive samples for one of the missing observations."

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CARBayesST/vignettes/CARBayesST.pdf

But I don't understand well how to obtain the posterior predictive values of Y, let's say I want to predict the value of Y for the next 3 periods for each zone. How should I do it?

This is the reproducible code (found in the vignette):

```
library(CARBayesST)
#################################################
#### Run the model on simulated data on a lattice
#################################################
#### set up the regular lattice
x.easting <- 1:10
x.northing <- 1:10
Grid <- expand.grid(x.easting, x.northing)
K <- nrow(Grid)
N <- 10
N.all <- N * K
#### set up spatial neighbourhood matrix W
distance <- as.matrix(dist(Grid))
W <-array(0, c(K,K))
W[distance==1] <-1
#### Simulate the elements in the linear predictor and the data
gamma <- rnorm(n=N.all, mean=0, sd=0.001)
x <- rnorm(n=N.all, mean=0, sd=1)
beta <- 0.1
Q.W <- 0.99 * (diag(apply(W, 2, sum)) - W) + 0.01 * diag(rep(1,K))
Q.W.inv <- solve(Q.W)
phi.temp <- mvrnorm(n=1, mu=rep(0,K), Sigma=(0.1 * Q.W.inv))
phi <- phi.temp
for(i in 2:N)
{
  phi.temp2 <- mvrnorm(n=1, mu=(0.8 * phi.temp), Sigma=(0.1 * Q.W.inv))
  phi.temp <- phi.temp2
  phi <- c(phi, phi.temp)
}
LP <- 3 + x * beta + phi
mean <- exp(LP)
Y <- rpois(n=N.all, lambda=mean)
#### Run the model
model <- ST.CARar(formula=Y~x, family="poisson", W=W, burnin=10,
                  n.sample=50)
```

Comment: following this post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/306973/how-to-predict-using-spatial-temporal-hierarchical-bayesian-models), I believe you need to set some of the values of the outcome column to NA. Once these are set to NA, the parameter `model$samples$y` should have estimates in the plausible range of values. You could then carry out a standard 'score' evaluation comparing the predicted Y to the actual Y.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment above, here is a reproducible answer:

```
            library(CARBayesST)
    #################################################
    #### Run the model on simulated data on a lattice
    #################################################
    #### set up the regular lattice
    x.easting <- 1:10
    x.northing <- 1:10
    Grid <- expand.grid(x.easting, x.northing)
    K <- nrow(Grid)
    N <- 10
    N.all <- N * K
    #### set up spatial neighbourhood matrix W
    distance <- as.matrix(dist(Grid))
    W <-array(0, c(K,K))
    W[distance==1] <-1
    #### Simulate the elements in the linear predictor and the data
    gamma <- rnorm(n=N.all, mean=0, sd=0.001)
    x <- rnorm(n=N.all, mean=0, sd=1)
    beta <- 0.1
    Q.W <- 0.99 * (diag(apply(W, 2, sum)) - W) + 0.01 * diag(rep(1,K))
    Q.W.inv <- solve(Q.W)
    phi.temp <- mvrnorm(n=1, mu=rep(0,K), Sigma=(0.1 * Q.W.inv))
    phi <- phi.temp
    for(i in 2:N)
    {
      phi.temp2 <- mvrnorm(n=1, mu=(0.8 * phi.temp), Sigma=(0.1 * Q.W.inv))
      phi.temp <- phi.temp2
      phi <- c(phi, phi.temp)
    }
    LP <- 3 + x * beta + phi
    mean <- exp(LP)
    Y <- rpois(n=N.all, lambda=mean)

    # Set last 51 observations to NA
    Y2 <- Y
    Y2[950:1000] <- NA
    Y2

    #### Run the model
    # NOTES: We changed Y to Y2; We increasted n.sample to 5000
    model <- ST.CARar(formula=Y2~x, family="poisson", W=W, burnin=10,
                      n.sample=5000) 

    # Access the predictions for the NA values
    model$samples$Y
    # Get mean (or median) of the column for the average posterior prediction
    colMeans(model$samples$Y)
```

Note how this prints out values for those 51 values set to NA. We can calculate a naive accuracy as:

`caret::RMSE(colMeans(model$samples$Y), Y[950:1000])`

Note I took the `colMeans`, although you may want to take the median.

You can also use other accuracy metrics to your liking. Note that increasing the `n.sample` parameter greatly increased my accuracy (and most examples you will see will have 20,000+).

This is my shot at the problem - I am working with a similar model set. Let me know what you think! Hope it is helpful.